# Hooking to a C function

Tags: iphone, ios, hook, core-telephony

I am wondering how do I hook to a function that is in the dylib, i.e. a C function.
My target is to hook to a function CTRegistrationSetCellularDataIsEnabled that is in CoreTelephony.

Thanks!

Comment: So you are aware: doing this in an app destined for the App Store will get it rejected.

Comment: Must everyone here include this comment in every post? Believe me, that most of the people asking question like this one ARE aware of this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need access to MobileSubtrate if you want any hope of hooking a dylib function, which is done like so (hooking a function called CFShow(), from [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate)):

```
 static void (*original_CFShow)(CFTypeRef obj);  // a function pointer to store the original CFShow().
 void replaced_CFShow(CFTypeRef obj) {         
  // our replacement of CFShow().
  printf("Calling original CFShow(%p)...", obj);
  original_CFShow(obj);                         // calls the original CFShow.
  printf(" done.\n");
}
// hook CFShow to our own implementation.
MSHookFunction(CFShow, replaced_CFShow, &original_CFShow);
// From now on any call to CFShow will pass through replaced_CFShow first.
CFShow(CFSTR("test"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [class dump](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/ClassDump)  to get the headers from the classes you need to use, and then call this function

Comment: My problem is that this function is a static C function inside a dylib, meaning I have to load its symbol via dlsym. BUT, for some reason, I get an error that the symbol cannot be found.. As I understood, this is because it is a function of a cydia tweak, meaning its stripped before it is packaged.. that's why there are no symbols... Do you know how can I overcome it? Thx!